# React.js is not applying styles from my .sass file

Tags: reactjs

I have the following .sass file in /src/style

```html
.error {
    color: red;
}
```

and the following line in app.js

```html
import "./style/styles.sass";
```

When the app renders a  , the red style is not applied.  Are there additional steps I need to take to import a SASS file and apply it's style rules?

Comment: Did you create the app using `create-react-app`? Can you show us where and how you added the error class?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the terminal?

Comment: I created this with create-react-app.  I used NPM to install sass (version 4 I think).  I don't get any errors in the console or command line window.

Comment: @user3794648 Missed my second question, _can you show us where and how you added the `error` class?_

Comment: Here's my  .scss file: .error {
    color: red;
}

.nav {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

Comment: Here's how I import it in app.js:  import "./style/styles.scss";

Comment: Here's the HTML rendered code:             <span className = "error">{this.state.error}</span>

Answer (score 0):

You need to have node-sass installed to get .scss and .sass files to work in CRA

You can install it like so:

```sh
$ npm install node-sass --save
$ # or
$ yarn add node-sass
```

[From the CRA docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet/)

Comment: I reinstalled node-sass. Still get the same result, no styles.

Comment: Is there something I need to import in my app.js file?

Answer (score 0):

You said

> Here's my .scss file: .error { color: red; } .nav { border: 1px solid blue; }

Therefore, the import should be this:

```js
import "./style/styles.scss";
```

**NOT** this:

```js
import "./style/styles.sass";
```

Comment: yea, I fixed that. Still no styles.

Comment: I also changed the file back to just styles.css and wrote import "./style/styles.css";
 in my app.js . Still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was that somehow, something deleted all the text in my .scss file.  I've restored that file and things are working now.  Thanks for all the help though.